# Typing the value to put into an object property properly

Tags: typescript, typing

I'm attempting to type the value that I need to put into the property of an object.  See below.

```
interface SliceStateType {
    TrptLimit: number;
    TrptOffset: number;
    someString: string;
    someBool:boolean;

}

interface SettingType {
    key: keyof SliceStateType;
    value: number | string | boolean;
}

const initialState: SliceStateType = {
    TrptLimit: 10,
    TrptOffset: 0,
    someString: 'my string',
    someBool:false,

};

// settings is the same shape as initialState
settings[key] = value as WHATGOESHERE;
```

I am trying to type `value` to the exact type of whatever `key` is.
I was thinking maybe `WHATGOESHERE` would be  `SliceStateType[typeof key]` but that does not work.
The error is `Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

I thought that would have returned the concrete type for that specific key.
I am trying to do something like

```
settings[keyOfSlice] = value as SliceStateType['tRptLimit'];
```

but replacing tRptLimit with something dynamic based on "key"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
function set<T extends Record<never, never>, K extends keyof T>(
  object: T, key: K, value: T[K]
) { 
  object[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: I would like to understand this more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I'm not sure if you can do exactly what you're trying to do, but I'm not quite sure what that is. Typescript "erases" the types when it converts to Javascript, so you can't access them "dynamically", which I think is what you are asking.

You can get the type of a specific property, using this notation I don't see in your code:

```
let foo1: SliceStateType['TrptLimit'] // number
```

Another thing you can do is extract all the keys from an object type using `keyof`:

```
let foo2: keyof SliceStateType = 'TrptLimit' // ok
let foo3: keyof SliceStateType = 'no' // not ok
```

But you can't write a strongly typed version of `settings[someVariable] = value`, unless `someVariable` is typed very specifically to a certain string (or set of strings). What follows are some of the possibilities:

```
let someVariable: 'TrptLimit' = 'TrptLimit'
settings[someVariable] = ... will expect a number
```

You can even specify the type as

```
let someVariable: 'TrptLimit' | 'TrptOffset' = 'TrptLimit'
settings[someVariable] = ... will expect a number
```

But if `someVariable` has other keys, you lose some specific type checking:

```
let someVariable: keyof SliceStateType = 'TrptLimit'
settings[someVariable] = ... number|string|boolean
```

I hope this helps. This can be confusing initially.

Comment: Thanks!
Based on a suggestion from another forum this worked.
```settings[key] = value as never```